# Вызов js кода в html

Tags: javascript, html

Попалось такое задание, не понимаю как с точки зрения синтаксиса это должно выглядеть в html  и js файлах. Ниже привожу текст задания и то, как я написала код, который естественно не работает.

Некоторый справочник представлен в виде дерева, каждый узел которого может быть, либо перечнем дочерних узлов (тип А), либо узлом с информацией (тип Б).

```
Узлы типа А имеют вид:
{
title: “Категория”, // заголовок узла
children: [] // список дочерних узлов
}
Узлы типа B имеют вид:
{
title: “Понятие”, // заголовок узла
image: “...”, // (необяз)URL-изображения
text: “...” // текст информации, который не должен отображаться как
// html (перед выводом нужно экранировать), строки в нем
// разделяются символами переноса строки “\n”
}
```

HTML-код справочника должен генерироваться автоматически. Входным параметром является корневой узел типа А.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Справочник по странам</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Tree.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div Landscape()></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Попыталась повторить синтаксис, как в задании, но там абсолютно ничего не работает

```
Russia()
{
title:"Россия",
children:["Landscape"]
}
Landscape()
{
title:"Пейзажи",
image:"img/moskva.jpg",
text:"Территория России, определяемая её конституцией, "
"составляет 17 125 191 км² (первое место по площади среди стран мира)" 
}
```

Comment: Извините за прямоту, но Ваш уровень знания javascript 0 или близок к нему? `JS` нельзя вот так вот просто вызывать из `html`. Также, ваши методы имеют некорректный синтаксис. `Tree.js` это так Ваш файл называется? Или же Вы свой `js` файл так обозвали? Вам следует начать изучение javascript с основ (mdn хороший ресурс для этого). Вам конечно, кто-нибудь да кинет здесь корректный, готовый код, но в чем смысл? Выполнить задание ради галочки?

Comment: Так получается, что уровень знания JS достаточно низкий, но не нулевой, но это первое же задание, которое нам дали (для тех кто изучает с нуля js). К сожалению нет времени (даже пары недель), чтобы все с основ изучать и по полочкам старательно раскладывать (хотя повторюсь, я начинала учить и уже что-то да знаю). Поэтому изучаю я все посредством поиска нужной информации, но вот для данной темы я таковой не нашла, поэтому обратилась за помощью

Comment: Либо ваш преподаватель садист, либо ваш уровень знания не соответствует его ожиданиям.

Comment: О том, как создавать элементы DOM, можете прочесть здесь http://web-answers.ru/questions-and-answers/javascript/jquery/jquery-kak-sozdat-element-neskolko-sposobov/

Comment: Синтаксис должен выглядеть так: list = {title: "A1", children: [{title: "B1", image: '...', text: '...'}, {title: "B2", image: '...', text: '...'}, {title: "A2", children: [{title: "B3", image: '...', text: '...'}]}]}

Comment: а нас мучали паскалем 15 лет назад :( как сейчас помню - нарисовать в досовском окне кнопки типа графического интерфейс надо было =)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получается, что вот так:

https://jsfiddle.net/osbjovLz/

Как добавить картинки думаю разберётесь...

```
const data = [
  {
    "title": "Parent 0",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Child 1",
        "text": "Text 1",
        "image": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"
      },
      {
        "title": "Child 2",
        "text": "Text 2",      
        "image": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "title": "Parent 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Child 1",
        "text": "Text 1",
        "image": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"
      },
      {
        "title": "Child 2",
        "text": "Text 2",      
        "image": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function processData(data) {

  const root = document.getElementById('root');
  console.log(root)


  data.map(parent => {
    root.appendChild(createParentNode(parent));
  })

}

function createParentNode(data) {

  const node = document.createElement('div');

  const titleNode = document.createElement('h3');
  titleNode.textContent = data.title;
  node.appendChild(titleNode);

  const children = data.children || [];

  children.map(child => {
    node.appendChild(createChildNode(child));
  })

  return node;

}

function createChildNode(data) {

  const node = document.createElement('div');

  const textNode = document.createElement('span');
  textNode.textContent = data.text;
  node.appendChild(textNode);

  return node;
}


function main() {
  processData(data);
}

main();
```